# Getting a tricky shortURL redirect

Tags: php, redirect, curl

I have often used either php get_headers() or cURL to resolve long URLs from short URLs. I'm having trouble with short URLS from Oktopost, such as this example: http://okt.to/4AOy96

Headers indicate there is no redirect from this URL, just returning http://okt.to/4AOy96:

```
Array
(
[0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[1] => Content-Type: text/html
[2] => Date: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 05:27:09 GMT
[3] => Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
[4] => Vary: Accept-Encoding
[5] => X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.7
[6] => Content-Length: 914
[7] => Connection: Close
)
```

But when I paste this link into a browser it IS redirecting me to a different destination page. Does that suggest some type of redirection on the part of the Oktopost server, which is just not "followable" via a typical header location? A little confused about what might be going on here.

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

As per the recommendations below, I'm trying to get back a cURL response so I can parse the meta refresh and get the URL that I need. Problem is, all my cURL attempts are getting stuck in an infinite loop. I've tried any number of option combinations, but with no luck.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://okt.to/4AOy96');
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.897.0 Safari/535.6'); 
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $html;
```

Just can't seem to kill the loop and get back the html.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the source code of response:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var form, hash, referer;

    form = document.createElement("form");
    hash = document.createElement("input");
    referer = document.createElement("input");

    referer.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    referer.setAttribute('name', 'referer');
    referer.setAttribute('value', '');

    hash.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hash.setAttribute('name', 'hash');
    hash.setAttribute('value', '4AOy96');

    form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
    form.setAttribute('action', '');

    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(form);

    form.appendChild(hash);
    form.appendChild(referer);


    form.submit();
</script>
```

JS is doing POST request after you receive 200 response.

Answer (score 1):

The site executes some javascript to refresh the page.
What you could do is make a request to okt.to and extract the meta tag which holds the url you want

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://bit.ly/1EnnAau" />
```

Comment: See my additional info, above. I know your recommendation would work but I'm stuck in an inite cURL loop trying to get back the html response.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with the infinite loop. When I run your code snippet it works perfectly fine ?

Comment: I figured out it was stupid mistake on my part. Was echo-ing the response out, which was causing a redirect in my browser. I'm now parsing the response with DOMDocument() and everything is working fine. Thanks for the assist. Much appreciated!